# OID: value is hex-coded

Tags: openssl, x509

I try to parse a X509-issuer-string.
For reasons I do not know some attributes are coded in OID.

E.g.

```
CN=TEST,DN=my.test.com,O=My State,C=MS,2.5.4.97=#130e414141505050
```

My question is about the last one. I am perfectly fine that it is not named but with the OID.

But I have no idea how to interpret the value. I expect it to be 2-digit-hex per character. But what about the first 4 numbers? That would be some control-characters.

414141505050 would be the value I expect (AAAPPP).

But what is the meaning of the first 4 bytes (130e)??

I did not find any definition of the coding of a hex-value for an OID.

I faked the values for privacy - so if it is a form of checksum it will be corrupt.

Thanks for help!

Comment: it would be better if you could post exact binary copy of the issuer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2.5.4.97` is the OID for `organizationIdentifier` (http://oid-info.com/get/2.5.4.97), which OpenSSL is printing as the OID because it doesn't have that in the OID to name map.

One presumes that the `#` is OpenSSL-ese for "this is the raw data, hex encoded".  The raw value is a DER encoded value.  `0x13` identifies that this is a (primitive encoding) Printable String.  The next byte (0x0E) says that it is 14 bytes long.

Since your `414141505050` is only 6 bytes long, one assumes that you originally had a longer value.

Comment: sounds pretty legit.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
May I ask if this is anywhere documented??

Comment: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/ASN1_STRING_print_ex.html talks about the \# printing form (which it calls a dump), and it looks like the DUMP_DER flag was set.  We then need to understand [IETF RFC 3280](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3280) (certificates), [ITU-T-REC X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.690-201508-I!!PDF-E&type=items) (BER/DER encoding) and [ITU-T-REC X.680](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-X.680-201508-I!!PDF-E&type=items) (the ASN.1 language).  It's all there, just... spread out.